# how to prevent richtextBox automatically scrolling at the top?

Tags: c#, scroll, richtextbox

i have developing an editor that have functionalities of loading txt,rtf files deleting,adding and commenting.i have developed all the parts, but there is a minor problem if i do some operation at the end of richtextbox after performing it automatically scroll up the top. you can see [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3O8HS_mOjDNSDJPR2JnSTlGa3M) for better understanding.

Comment: Did you tried to use the CaretPosition? That is, store the the current position of the Caret in a temp variable before editing; do the edit; set the position of the Caret using the temp variable.

Comment: how do i use caret position?

Comment: actually i have richtextbox with autosroll property set to fasle added in to a panel with autosize property set to true that is added in to another panel with autoscroll property set to true which helps to scroll the text. please tell me solution

Comment: Google "RichTextBox Caret position", you'll find everything you need, and other StackOverflow questions that deal with the problem.